# Difference between logical implication and conjunction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

If we are asked to convert the following two phrases into a mathematical expression, what will be the difference between using a logical implication and a conjunction expression?

If we have $$P(x) = \text{x is an accountant} \\ \text{and} \\ Q(x) = \text{x owns a car}$$

and for the phrase *"All accountants own cars"*, which one should be correct? And what is the difference?
$$
\forall x, (P(x) \implies Q(x)) \ \text{and} \ \forall x, (P(x) \wedge Q(x))
$$

Similarly, for the phrase *"All car owners are accountants"*:
$$
\forall x,(Q(x) \implies P(x)) \ \text{and} \ \forall x,(Q(x) \wedge P(x))
$$

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall x(P(x)\to Q(x))$ means all accountants own cars; $\forall x(P(x)\land Q(x))$ means everyone is an accountant with a car; $\forall x(Q(x)\to P(x))$ means whoever owns a car is an accountant; $\forall x(Q(x)\land P(x))$ means everyone is a car-owning accountant.

Comment: So for both phrases I should use logical implications right? Because if I use conjonction it would be everybody is accountant while the sentence means only IF this person is an accountant

Comment: @YanZhuang Got it in one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem becomes easier to attack if you realize that as far as boolean truth tables are concerned, the following two statements are logically equivalent:

$A \Rightarrow B$

(not $A$) or ($B$).